# Ripping DVD to Play in XBox 360

Tags: ffmpeg, mencoder, xbox-360, handbrake

I am trying to rip a dvd to be playable on my XBox 360. I used Handbrake 0.9.8 Normal & High Profile presets with no avail. Although [MPEG-4 & H.264](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/watch-dvds-movies) are supported by the XBox, it won't play files made by Handbrake in those formats.

Is there a way to encode files using ffmpeg, mencoder or any other tool and have them work in the XBox 360?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to play DVD on xbox is to burn AVI (Divx/xvid) format to a disc, you can get loads on one disc as well.

I personally could not get h264 to work on my xbox but avi works great, you can open the CD like a flash drive and just choose the file you want to play.

You can use k9copy from software center to rip your dvd to avi.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is your tool of choice on ubuntu to get an AVI from the DVD?

Comment: check out k9copy hears a tutorial http://linuxowns.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/how-to-rip-a-dvd-in-ubuntu-to-avi-the-easy-way/

Comment: As a side note I read only the US xbox supports h264/x264 playback dont know if this is true or not but could be

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you [can use ffmpeg](http://hellalame.com/how-to-convert-h264-hdavc-mts-m2ts-video-for-the-xbox-360-using-linux/). An example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -y -f mov -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -coder 1 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me umh -subq 5 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -refs 3 -bf 3 -trellis 1 -ab 128kb -b 1321k -f mov output.mov
```